# Placement of the adverb せめて

Tags: grammar, usage, adverbs

I'm trying to form the sentence "Could you at least call me when you get there?", and I'm unsure whether to put せめて at the beginning like せめて着いたら、電話してくれない？ or in between like 着いたら、せめて電話してくれない？ I figured that so long as it came before the verb 電話する I could go either way with it, but I'm not sure what sounds more natural.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both positions are okay and natural. せめて connects to only an expression of desire (したい), suggestion (しよう) or order/request (しなさい/しろ), so there is no source of confusion.